# How can I replace the result of a getelementbyid to show a text link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below:

```
 $('a').on('click', function () {
     $('#show').html($(this).attr('data-owner') + '<br><img src="' + $(this).attr('data-owner_logo') + '"/><br>' + '<br>' + $(this).attr('data-owner_url'));
```

I have amended it so that data-owner_logo returns an image in the html div, but how can I amend the code so that the data-owner_url returns a clickable link as specified text (e.g. 'More info') instead of the full url? Any help appreciated, I have tried everything!
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but If I understood correctly, you just need to use `<a href="urlInHere">More Info</a>`. Let me know if this helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `html()` is not the best function to call here but if you must:

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
   $('#show').html(... + '<a href="' + $(this).attr('data-owner_url')
       + '">More info</a>'
   );
```

I prefer to use `append()`, it's more readable (but slower):

```
 $('#show')
      .empty() // clear node
      .append(document.createTextNode($(this).attr('data-owner')))
      .append($('<br />'))
      .append($('<img />').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-owner_logo')))
      .append($('<br />'))
      .append($('<a />').attr('href', $(this).attr('data-owner_url')).text('More info'))
 ;
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, thank you for this. I used the append as you suggested. The problem is when I click on another data owner it just adds the link and image rather than replace it. I take it I just need to include a remove on click to go back to the start??

Comment: Insert `.empty()` before the first `.append()` - that removes all existing children of the node.